# Diff command to compare files which are in first directory only

Tags: diff

I have 2 folders whose contents I want to compare. For instance I have folder 1 and folder 2. Folder 2 has a lot of new files + some files same as folder 1 but with some changes in contents of these files. Now, I want to compare folder 1 and folder 2 to get the list of folder 1 files which are changed or missing in folder 2.

When I run following command:

```
diff --brief -r folder1/ folder2/ > diff.txt
```

It also gives me the list of new files of folder 2.

I want to compare folder 1 and folder 2 to get the list of only those files of folder 1 which are missing or changed in folder 2.

How can I achieve this ?

Please don't recommend `Meld`, I already tried it and it's of no help. I figured, command line would be faster.

**UPDATE**

```
find folder1 -type f -exec diff --brief --from-file=folder2 {} +
```

doesn't give me the full file path of the differed/missing files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following worked :

```
diff --brief -r folder1/ folder2/ | grep folder1/ > diff.txt
```

Comment: Please add a short description so OP knows how it works.

Answer (score 4):

The `--from-file` option might be of use:

```
$ diff -r --brief foo bar
Files foo/a and bar/a differ
Files foo/b and bar/b differ
Files foo/c and bar/c differ
Only in bar: d
$ diff --brief --from-file=bar foo/*
Files bar/a and foo/a differ
Files bar/b and foo/b differ
Files bar/c and foo/c differ
```

So, in your case, it would be:

```
diff --brief --from-file=folder2 folder1/*
```

There's also the `--unidirectional-new-file` option:

```
--unidirectional-new-file
      treat absent first files as empty
```

With it:

```
$ diff /tmp/foo/ /tmp/bar -r --brief --unidirectional-new-file
Files /tmp/foo/a and /tmp/bar/a differ
Files /tmp/foo/b and /tmp/bar/b differ
Files /tmp/foo/c and /tmp/bar/c differ
```

Comment: your command gives error for all the files which are only in 1 folder saying no such path found. In order to make the command work I have to remove * after folder1/ .. Then it only gives me first level of directory tree's difference. If i run it with -r it no longer lists formatted output like "Common subdirectories" , etc.

Comment: If you have nested directories, then try something like `find folder1 -type f -exec diff  --brief --from-file=folder2  {} +`

Comment: @ReenaParekh I don't understand your edited command. Please edit your post to include a clear set of input and expected output.

Comment: @ReenaParekh also see the update with `--unidirectional-new-file`

Answer (score 0):

To compare recursively, unilaterally and efficiently, this shell function is a good general solution:

```sh
function diffruni {
    local a="$1" b="$2"
    shift 2
    # get relative paths, protected by nul, and iterate them
    find "$b/" -printf '%P\0' | while IFS= read -d '' path; do
        # Give an error like diff's when destination side doesn't exist
        if ! [ -e "$a/$path" ]; then
            echo "Only in $b: $path"
        # don't double-compare entire directory contents
        elif ! [ -d "$b/$path" ]; then
            diff "$@" "$a/$path" "$b/$path"
        fi
    done
}
```

Usage: `diffruni dest source --brief` or `diffruni dest source --unified`
The first two params are the folders to compare, any after that are treated as options to `diff`.

I found that other suggestions produced excessive output when used against large trees, or failed with options like `--unified`.